# Is it valid to authenticate a message by decrypting and validating the format of the plain text?

Tags: encryption, authentication

I'm wanting to validate a message came from a trusted source, and I'm wanting the message encrypted. I can share keys securely beforehand. The catch is that I'm very limited in the number of characters in each message (maximum worst case encrypted & armored message length ~300 characters which is acceptable, but high).

It seems the "correct" way of doing this might with signing? I'm not really familiar with the workflow, and I'm concerned about the length that would add or other complications.

Given that I can format my encrypted message however I want, is it valid to simply decrypt and validate that the message has the right format (10 character identifier, followed by 5 numeric characters, etc.)?

Comment: Is the identifier fixed or can they be any value? From what range? Same question for the numeric characters. If the characters are ascii and the numbers 0-10 then by using a binary encoding you could use the space saved for a magic number which makes the risk of collision much lower.

Comment: Simplest solution is to just use GCM.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald - The 300 character limit implies an environment where the message isn't sent over internet. Just the http + tcp headers would likely be over 300 bytes..

Comment: The identifier would be a fixed/know value. I'm using ASCII encoding because in reality the message is coming from a QR code, and a binary encoding would likely break some things. The system will not be connected to the internet, so cloud systems aren't an option either unfortunately.

Comment: @Hector he is referring to the GCM mode of operation of AES, not a google cloud service.

Comment: @Hector The overhead is at most 16 bytes, which would be at most 24 characters in base64 (for the authentication tag, IV would be extra if that's included), I didn't suggest using http at all.

Comment: Aw, I was confused as well and thought you were referring to a cloud service. (I'm new to this) If it only adds 16-24 base64 characters then I will definitely look into it.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald - Apologies. Now I feel like an idiot...

Comment: @Hector No worries, I didn't realize GCM stood for something else. I'll be sure to refer to it as AES-GCM next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments already suggest, this is a good scenario to be using AES-[GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), the Gallois/Counter mode of operation.

From the linked source:

> The operation is an authenticated encryption algorithm designed to
>   provide both data authenticity (integrity) and confidentiality. GCM is
>   defined for block ciphers with a block size of 128 bits

Other modes that authenticate the message with an additional MAC might work as well but as GCM is available, this might very well be the best suited option.

As to answer your actual question of just going with anything that decrypts to intelligible text:

This is not a good idea. There is a - small - probability that an attacker might alter the cipher text and it decrypts to valid plain text that wasn’t the original plain text.

While there is no known attack on AES to gain any significant advantage over randomly flipping bits to accomplish that, using GCM provides way better authentication, removes the possibility of human failure and offer this for little overhead, so GCM should be the choice here.